# What is the fastest / memory / size efficient Java Serialisation framework based on Benchmarks?

Tags: java, serialization, benchmarking

What is the fastest / memory / size efficient Java Serialisation framework based on Benchmarks?

There are claims that Kryo is the fastest. Also Jackson Smile and also NFS-RPC. Are there any solid comparisons backed by numbers and perhaps other lesser know frameworks which give better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this nice [comparison](http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking). Have a look at this and decide for yourselves.

Comment: Just to throw another one into the mix; ASN1 does binary serialisation, and it stands a good chance of being the smallest if Packed Encoding Rules are used, and is probably quite fast too. Tools can be a bit thin on the ground; it might be worth looking at Objective System's toolset (not free) if interested.